# Record voice and apply effects

Tags: android, mediarecorder, audiotrack

I want to record voice from the microphone and apply some effects like, robot, echo, squirrel.

I did some research and I have found this classes:

- [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)
- [MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html)

I would like to know what is the best option to achieve this?
Also I want to share by whatsapp, telegram, etc after that, then I need a common audio format output like wav, mp3, etc.

Comment: A working sample code is available at https://github.com/sachinvarma/VoiceChanger.

Comment: in realtime its actually difficult and cannot be done via ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to modify wave data in certain ways, to achieve that effects, you need to record wave data directly by AudioRecord. You can obtain 8- or 16-bit samples data and do whatever you want.

If you want to record a file in particular format, and call some external tool to apply effect, it could be done with MediaRecorder.

Some effects (e.g. reverberation) can be added to sound during playback, when using MediaPlayer.

Comment: Thanks, but wich library I should use to modify the wave data? The output file of AudioRecord is PCM, this is not supported by whatsapp. I can convert it in mp3 or wav with effects easily?